# Can't login - permission denied

Tags: login

I'm using Kubuntu. I tried to create a script in `/bin/usr/mouse.sh` and make it executable. I also deleted and created the folder several times. Now I can't login to the system. The error is

```
-bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Help!

Upd
`namei -mo /bin/sh` output:

```
f: /bin/sh
drwxr-rx-x root root /
drwxr-rx-x root root bin
drwxrwxrwx root root sh
```

Comment: `/bin/usr` or `/usr/bin`? Which folder did you delete? Can you login to the TTY (Ctrl-Alt-F1/F2)?

Comment: I deleted /bin/sh Yes, I can login through these

Comment: Ok, edit your post and add the output of `namei -mo /bin/sh`.

Comment: I think you need to create a symlink with /bin/dash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run below command in your terminal.

```
sudo ln /bin/dash /bin/sh
```

Comment: Becareful with when you play with core files :)